# JWTAuth::fromUser($user) return nothing?

Tags: php

$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

tried to create token but nothing created
tried to create token but nothing created
tried to create token but nothing created
tried to create token but nothing created
tried to create token but nothing created
tried to create token but nothing created
tried to create token but nothing created

tried to call this method but not worked